# scale fonts together with controls

Tags: .net, winforms

With WinForms, I can use `Control.Scale` to scale a control larger.  When I do that, all child controls are repositioned and scaled correctly, but font size remains the same.

Is there an easy way to force font to scale up/down, or is the only way to manually update font for all controls when control is being scaled?

Background:  I'm working on a program in which I need to support zoom in/out to make labels, textboxs, etc. more readable for users with poor eyesight.

Comment: you might want to create some kinda layout manager then anyway which will do it...I think this is what we did in our case
WPF might be able to do it itself..

Comment: have to use .NET 2. I can update write hode to update fonts, but wanted to avoid doing extra work if .NET supports this out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find solution so I ended up scaling font by hand.

I'm using [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/) *highly recommended, great controls library) which supports themes. I simply used reflection to find all font properties and scale them up.

Answer (score 2):

Do it the other way around.  Change the font size, the controls will automatically scale to accommodate the larger font.  For example:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    float mDesignSize;
    int mIncrement;
    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      mDesignSize = this.Font.SizeInPoints;
    }
    private void adjustFont() {
      float size = mDesignSize * (1 + mIncrement / 7f);
      this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, size);
    }
    private void btnIncreaseFontSize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      mIncrement += 1;
      adjustFont();
    }
    private void btnDecreateFontSize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      mIncrement -= 1;
      adjustFont();
    }
  }
```

Comment: this won't scale controls location. I can use table layout, but it has it's own drawbacks.